# Including Rails configuration in my cucumber env.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, cucumber

I'd like to access `Rails.config` inside my cucumber `env.rb` file, as my configuration specifies a temporary directory that I want to clean before I run my tests. How can I access `Rails.config` inside my `env.rb` file?

Comment: Is the temporary directory generated at random? If not, it be easier to specify the name of the directory in a constant, and then just reference that in your `env.rb` file.

Comment: It's is a constant which is specified in my `Rails.config`, I'd rather not have to specify it in two places in case it ever changes.

Comment: If the constant is defined outside of the `module Your App ... end` block, then it will be available globally in your application.